# Find'n'Replace non-empty cell with unique value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where each row is either blank, has column A beginning with a P, or has column A beginning with an asterisk (an old text file). The value of P needs to be unique throughout the file - can be letters or numbers, but with a P prefix. I do not want to change the blank or asterisk cells.

So for example:

```
*** Block 1 ***

P1 <some data>
P1 <some data>
P1A <some data>

*** Block 2 ***

P2 <some more data>
P2 <some more data>
```

Needs to become something like:

```
*** Block 1 ***

P0001 <some data>
P0002 <some data>
P0003 <some data>

*** Block 2 ***

P0004 <some more data>
P0005 <some more data>
```

Though I can use "Find" to match all the P cells, I don't know if there is a way of making "replace" insert some unique text (or ever incrementing number). I suspect I need some code/macro. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate solution that does not use VBA, you could do the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Find and Replace
- Click on Options to expand and see all options
- Find what = `p*`
- Assuming the `<some data>` column is column B, set Replace with = `="P"&TEXT(COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW())),"0000")`
- Within = `Sheet`
- Search = `By Rows`
- Look in = `Formulas`
- Match Case should be **unchecked**
- Match entire cell contents should be **checked**
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>
- Assuming your data that you replaced was in column A,
  select column A and then copy -> right-click -> paste special ->
  values

Screenshot of what the Find/Replace dialogue should look like:

[image]

Remember that last step to turn column A into values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub FixTheP()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    i = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each r In Range("A1:A" & N)
        If Left(r.Text, 1) = "P" Then
            r.Value = "P" & Format(i, "0000")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```